# how to proof that this function is zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> given $f$ continuous and diferentiable into $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ and $f(0)=0$ then proof that $f(x)=0$

atempt:

taking $x>0$, since $f$ is continuous then by mean value theorem exist a $\xi\in[0,x]$ that

$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}\iff f(x)= xf'(\xi)$$

wich gives

$$|f'(x)|\le|xf'(\xi)|\le|xf(\xi)|$$

and $x=0\Rightarrow |f'(0)|\le|f(0)|=0\Rightarrow f'(0)=0$.

but i only able to find $f'(0)=0$, how to solve this problem?

Comment: This can also be done as a special case of Gromwell's inequality.  It was on my analysis qual :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Assume $f(x) \not\equiv 0$. Then there is some $x'$ such that $f(x') \ne 0$.
By MVT we get the existence of a $\xi\in[0,x']$ with
$$|f(\xi)| \ge |f'(\xi)| = \left|\frac{f(x')}{x'}\right|$$
Thus if $|x'| < 1$ we get that $\xi < x'$ and $f(\xi)\ne 0$. Use this Ansatz to prove that $f\equiv 0$ in $[0,1]$ and translate $f$ to $f(x+c)$ to conclude.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong?